# Creating a redux middleware that uses websocket api for syncing server data state with client

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs

I have a server API, that is based on websockets. If the client connects, he must first send a message, and if a success message from server is emitted, client can start working with the server data.

Now i have a angular4 based app, that if the user opens several view components, each component registers to specific events from the API (Using a Websockets service). If the a new state comes from server, the views can update itself. Views can also send update events to server, that recalculates data and sends updates via websockets. The server itself holds a state of the data.

But now, no real client state exists. Without overcomplicating this post (i exclude routing etc), the main target for me now is to integrate redux for managing the state in UI, so that the user can reload the page and see last opened views with a synced with server data.

The current approach of me, is to create create a

1. Backend service, that holds an WebSocketSubject (RxJS) and manages the sending or recieving from server. I pass an connection observable, that dispatches an event if connection exist. I also have a Subscription inside the service, that dispatches all the websockets push messages as redux events and acts like a middleware

```js
    /** this code is a binding to redux word, and acts as middleware push
     * @type {Subscription}
     */
    this.subscription = this.socket$.subscribe(
      (msg) => this.ngRedux.dispatch({type: msg.method, value: msg.parameters}),
      (err) => this.ngRedux.dispatch({type: AppActions.CONNECTION_FAILED}),
      () => this.ngRedux.dispatch({type: AppActions.CONNECTION_CLOSED})
    );
```

The idea is that i will have reducers, that will react on data state changes from server e.g. if an error is send and a specific view listens to it, it should have a error state.

```html
    case BackendStreams.some__error:
      return Object.assign({}, lastState, {
        error: 'Could not do some calcucations'
      });
```

The server code itself is deterministic and works works the messages from one stack, so i can expect that if i send same 4 messages in same sequence, i will receive same responses.

The problem what i have now, is that if i reload the window (or use the DevTools), the state is recreated, but none of the events are resent to backend. How can i accomplish this? Should i somehow (what tools) tell Redux that some of impurity exists, or have something like a state machine? Im just guessing...

Comment: Not really answering here, but you might want to take a look into "logux" :)

Comment: i rather would use sagas or redux-observables :)

Comment: Oh my bad!!! I thout @Sonne was using ngrx... Well you should definitely use ngrx with Angular :)